# Can analogue Hall sensors be used in BLDC for static angle measurement?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, encoder

Everything I have read on using Hall sensors with BLDC motors appears to use latching hall sensors which provide repeatable latching angles as the magnetic fields change at specific angles. I am wondering if an analogue hall sensor can be used to provide intermediate angles for static angle measurements are ever used? And if not then why?

Comment: Yes. There are ICs dedicated to this. Latching/digital hall sensors are used to commutate BLDCs trapezoidal because nothing more is needed for that task. A sinusoidally commutated BLDC on the other hand would need specific angular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I have answered my own question in the affirmative by finding the paper: 
[Position Estimation and Control of Compact BLDC Motors Based on
Analog Linear Hall Effect Sensors](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~todorov/papers/SimpkinsACC10.pdf) which all though specific to pancake styled motors I'm sure is adaptable to traditional radial flux motors.

Also found information on analogue hall sensors being used in commercial motors in [FAULHABER application note 162 Analog Hall Sensors](https://www.faulhaber.com/fileadmin/user_upload_global/support/MC_Support/Encoder/AppNotes/Faulhaber_AN162_EN.pdf)

Comment: FYI from personal experiments dropping linear halls with suitable sensitivity ranges directly in the slots provided for latching halls in some motors gives a trapezoidal signal. While the flat spots in the signal mean you don't get full angular coverage, the slopes in the signal do give enough advance warning of pole changes to be able to do something about torque ripple down to speeds approaching zero.